# need to split the one string value into multiple columns based on different special characters or witout characters

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have one string column. I need to split into multiple columns.
The data is like below

---

| tags | status |
| --- | --- |
| test | Open |
| _test | Open |
| test_ | Open |
| 1200>test> | IP |
| 1200>test>234598 | completed |

I need to split the above into multiple columns as like below

Deptno,empname,Empno

My desired output like below

```
----------------  ------------ -------   -------- ------
tags              |    status | EmpNO | EmpName  |DepNo|
---------------   |-----------|------ |---------- ------
|test             |   Open    | NULL  |test      | NULL |
|_test            |   Open    | NULL  |test      | NULL |
|test_            |   Open    | NULL  |test      | NULL |
|1200>test>       |   IP      | NULL  |test      | 1200 |
|1200>test>234598 |  completed| 234598|test      | 1200 |
```

I have written query and able to split the data into multiple columns. But it is not handling all scenario's.

Query:

```
SELECT [tags],substring([tags], 1 , CHARINDEX('>', [tags])-1) as 'Division',
SUBSTRING([tags],CHARINDEX('>', [tags]) + 1,LEN([tags]) - CHARINDEX('>', [tags]) - CHARINDEX('-', REVERSE([tags])) ),
REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE([tags]), 1 , CHARINDEX('>', REVERSE([tags]))-1)) AS 'EmpNo' 
FROM ods.[testtable]
```

Could someone help me the query.

Comment: Can you please provide a sample data with desired result

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have pasted data in above. I am pasting here tags               status    

test               Open
_test              Open
test_              Open
1200>test>          IP
1200>test>234598   completed

Comment: What is your expected outcome? Please realize we do not know or understand your data, so adding some clarification would help us a lot in figuring out what exactly you are trying to achieve. 
In 1200 > test > 234598, is 1200 the `DeptNo`, test the `empname`, and 234598 your `EmpNo`? Is `DeptNo` the same as `Division` in your query? What situations is it handling, and where is it falling short?

Comment: Sorry. I have added my required output.

Comment: I am able to handle the 1200>test>234598 this kind of data. I am not able to handle test_ and _test kind of data. With my query I am getting error as Msg 537, Level 16, State 3, Line 4
Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.

Answer (score 1):

According to the desired result a query would be like:

```
SELECT RIGHT(tags, CASE 
        WHEN p2.pos = 0
            THEN 0
        ELSE LEN(tags) - p2.pos
        END) AS EmpNO
,SUBSTRING(tags, CASE 
        WHEN p1.pos = 0
            THEN p1.pos
        ELSE p1.pos + 1
        END, CASE 
        WHEN p2.pos = 0
            THEN LEN(tags) + 1
        ELSE P2.Pos - P1.Pos - 1
        END) AS EmpName
,LEFT(tags, CASE 
        WHEN p1.pos = 0
            THEN 0
        ELSE p1.pos - 1
        END) AS DepNo
,*
FROM ods.[testtable]
CROSS APPLY (
SELECT (charindex('>', tags))
) AS P1(Pos)
CROSS APPLY (
SELECT (charindex('>', tags, P1.Pos + 1))
) AS P2(Pos)
```

I used this post to create the query [Post](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/42393/get-the-2nd-or-3rd-occurrence-of-a-value-in-a-delimited-string/42398)

Comment: Everyone is here awesome. This is also working. Thanks a lot to everyone

Answer (score 1):

Using your sample data the follow would appear to give your desired results:

```
select tags, status,
    Empno.v EmpNo,
    Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(tags,'_',''),IsNull(Depno.v,''),''),isnull(Empno.v ,''),''),'>','') EmpName,
    Depno.v Depno
from t
cross apply (values(CharIndex('>', tags)-1))v1(t1)
cross apply (values(CharIndex('>', Reverse(tags))-1))v2(t2)
cross apply (values(Left(tags,NullIf(t1,-1))))Depno(v)
cross apply (values(right(tags,Iif(t2>0,t2,null))))Empno(v)
```

Comment: It is working perfectly. Thanks a lot